# How to save extra field values using has_may :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have these models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # fields: name, weight, expiry_date, active...

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  # fields: name, active...

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, :through => :categorizations
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  # fields: user_id, type, priority, product_id, category_id...

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category

  validates :user_id, :presence =>  { :message => "Must be filled" }
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.select :category_ids .... {:multiple => true} %>
<% end %>
```

parameters:

```
{"product"=>{"name"=>"sdf", "category_ids" => ["1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
```

**Question:** How to save the some additional fields like user_id, priority in categoriztion table?

I tried to access categorization object after initialize product but there is empty array. for example

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product]) # {"product"=>{"name"=>"sdf", "category_ids" => ["1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Update Document"}
@product.categorizations => []
```